# How to show checkbox setting when checkbox checked?

Tags: checkbox

I want to set a range option to choose, if a user selects Abslote then he can choose a date (start date and End date),
else if a user select Quice then he can choose the select list("15min","1hour"...)

My code as below,

```
<script>
change(element,elementtobechanged)
 {
   if(document.getElementsByName(element)[0].checked)
 {     
   document.getElementsByName(elementtobechanged)[0].disabled  = true;
  }
}
</script>

 <input type="checkbox" name="absolute"  onchange="change(this,'s1');" Absolute</p>
   <div id="s1">
   <div class="demo-section k-content">
    <p style="margin-top: 2em">Start date:</p>
        <input id="start" style="width: 100%;" value=""  onFocus="this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" disabled/>
        <p style="margin-top: 2em">End date:</p>
       <input id="end" style="width: 100%;" value="" onFocus="this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" disabled/>
    </div>
    </div>
   <input type="checkbox" name="quick"  onchange="change(this,'s2');"                                Quick
    <div id="s2" >
    <select name="quickselect" id="quickselect"  disabled>
    <option value="15">Last 15 minutes</option>
    <option value="12h">Last 12 hour</option>
   <option value="24h">Last 24 hour</option>
   </select>
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Dude I added the code take a look it disables from checkbox to checkbox.

```
 Hey I guess you can disable the checkboxes based on the user input.

    For Example:

    If user select's the quick, then disable the absolute checkbox and the option provided.you can use javascript to disable and enable based onclick.

    Answer:
    You can use the onchange event in javascript and then check both the checkboxes.checked value and then choose the decision of making the deselect the 
    other checkbox.

    change(element,elementtobechanged)
    {
     if(document.getElementsByName(element)[0].checked)
     {     
         document.getElementsByName(elementtobechanged)[0].disabled  = true;
     }
    }
While calling send 'this', and the other element to disabled.
The Code to disable the checkbox is
    <html>

<head>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
    function change(element, elementtobechanged) {
      if (document.getElementsByName(element)[0].checked) {
        document.getElementsByName(elementtobechanged)[0].disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementsByName(elementtobechanged)[0].disabled = false;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>       
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" name="absolute" onChange="change(this.name,'quick');" Absolute</p>
  <div id="s1">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
      <p style="margin-top: 2em">Start date:</p>
      <input id="start" style="width: 100%;" value="" onFocus="this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" />
      <p style="margin-top: 2em">End date:</p>
      <input id="end" style="width: 100%;" value="" onFocus="this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="quick" onChange="change(this.name,'absolute');" Quick <div id="s2">
  <select name="quickselect" id="quickselect">
    <option value="15">Last 15 minutes</option>
    <option value="12h">Last 12 hour</option>
    <option value="24h">Last 24 hour</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi shankar,i have modified code as you said ,but still cannot disable the other checkboxes